# how to use clone method in java program

Tags: java

i wanted to know exacly what effect it will bring to the program?  i have seen several example in Web but could not make out example whats this?

I have only knew this point:
the ability to create an object with similar state as the original object.
To do so:

- Implement Cloneable
- Override the clone() method
- Make it public In clone() call super.clone() and then copy any mutable object's state

Anyone please give a simple example on this topic !

Comment: It sounds like you already understand it. What's missing?

Comment: @ChrisMartin please convert that in a simple example

Comment: `clone()` is rarely the right solution. The behaviour is ill defined and it has problems with final fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clone** is a Greek word meaning “branch”, referring to the process whereby a new plant can be created from a twig. In biology it is about copying the DNAs.

In java, it essentially means the ability to create an object with similar state as the original object. The clone() method provides this functionality. In java, though clone is ‘intended’ to produce a copy of the same object it is not guaranteed. Clone comes with lots of ifs and buts.

By default, java cloning is ‘*field by field copy*’ i.e. as the Object class does not have idea about the structure of class on which clone() method will be invoked. So, JVM when called for cloning, do following things:

1. If the class has only primitive data type members then a completely new copy of the object will be created and the reference to the new object copy will be returned
2. If the class contains members of any class type then only the object references to those members are copied and hence the member references in both the original object as well as the cloned object refer to the same object

Apart from above default behavior, you can always override this behavior and specify your own.

As per java Doc (formatted and extract).

```
The general intent is that, for any object x, the expression:
1) x.clone() != x will be true   ---- means that cloned object will have separate memory address assignment
2) x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass() will be true, but these are not absolute requirements. ---- means original and cloned objects should have same class type, but it is not mandatory
3) x.clone().equals(x) will be true, this is not an absolute requirement. ---- means original and cloned objects should have be equal using equals() method, but it is not mandatory
```

**Shallow copy** Generally clone method of an object, creates a new instance of the same class and copies all the fields to the new instance and returns it. This is nothing but shallow copy. objects contained within it will not be copied To the cloned object. Example –

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable{

private String employeeName;
private Department department;

:
:
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
return super.clone();
}
}
```

**Deep copy** Deep copy copies everything. But you have to implement it yourself.

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable{

:
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Employee cloned = (Employee)super.clone();
    // get the Department object of “this” Employee and make copy of it and assign it to Employee object 
    cloned.setDepartment((Department)cloned.getDepartment().clone());
    return cloned;
}}
}
```

**Point to remember**

1. When you dont know whether you can call the clone() method of a
   particular class as you are not sure if it is implemented in that
   class, you can check with checking if the class is instance of
   "Cloneable" interface as below.

   if(obj1 instanceof Cloneable){
       obj2 = obj1.clone();
   }
2. As Cloneabe interface is a marker interface (dont have any methods
   in it), you can never cast an object to Cloneable and call clone()
   method. Check below.

   //Dont do this. Cloneabe dont have any methods
   obj2 = (Cloneable)obj1.clone();
3. No constructor is called on the object being cloned. So, you have to
   make sure all the members have been properly set.
4. If the class has final fields, these can’t be given a value in the
   clone method.
5. If your class is singleton, you have to take care of the cloning

   public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
       throw new CloneNotSupportedException(); 
   }

Answer (score 0):

Rules of cloning

> ```
> Creates and returns a copy of this object. The precise meaning of "copy" may depend on the class of the object.
> The general intent is that, for any object x, the expression:
> 1) x.clone() != x will be true
> 2) x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass() will be true, but these are not absolute requirements.
> 3) x.clone().equals(x) will be true, this is not an absolute requirement.
> ```

[Here is a example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/)
A class `Employee` to be cloned:

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable{

    private int empoyeeId;
    private String employeeName;
    private Department department;

    public Employee(int id, String name, Department dept)
    {
    this.empoyeeId = id;
    this.employeeName = name;
    this.department = dept;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
    }
    //Accessor/mutators methods will go there
    }

public class Department
{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Department(int id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //Accessor/mutators methods will go there
}
```

So, if we need to clone the Employee class, then we need to do something like this.

```
public class TestCloning {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        Department dept = new Department(1, "Human Resource");
        Employee original = new Employee(1, "Admin", dept);
        //Lets create a clone of original object
        Employee cloned = (Employee) original.clone();
        //Let verify using employee id, if cloning actually workded
        System.out.println(cloned.getEmpoyeeId());

        //Verify JDK's rules

        //Must be true and objects must have different memory addresses
        System.out.println(original != cloned);

        //As we are returning same class; so it should be true
        System.out.println(original.getClass() == cloned.getClass());

        //Default equals method checks for refernces so it should be false. If we want to make it true,
        //we need to override equals method in Employee class.
        System.out.println(original.equals(cloned));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
true
true
false
```

Comment: i have already seen this example in a site http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/   , i am looking for a simple example which you can make it by youself